# Centering a next and previous buttons at the bottom of my html page

Tags: html, css, button, flexbox

I would like to center my **next** and **previous** buttons. Right now they are currently on the far left side of the page. Code was taken from w3schools and I am just scratching my head right now just as to how to center this dang thing! Here is what I have right now. I am currently liking the round icons so that is what I chose.

I put them in a div hoping that it can move both **previous** and **next** icons to be centered, but no luck right now at the moment. Run the code snippet and you'll see what I'm talking about and you can see that the icons are not center.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.previous {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.next {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.round {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="nextPreviousButtons">
  <a href="#" class="previous round">&#8249;</a>
  <a href="about.html" class="next round">&#8250;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you need it should be centered at the bottom or just it should be centralised

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Azazel: Try this code Hope it works!
if you need it should be the only center then just add these properties but you need it be center.justify-content: center it center horizontally, where align-items: center is center vertically.

```
.nextPreviousButtons {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

}

or if you want it should be center at the bottom then use this code

```
.nextPreviousButtons {
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 50%;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks guys! The first option was a big help! Since when did centering things start getting more complicated or just a why TF kind of questions! CSS just sometimes makes centering things so complicated these days.

Comment: @Azazel: Great!! it works for you means I added two codes because in your question you mention bottom of HTML page it should be center.

Comment: You make a good point! Still a noob at CSS stuff. Anyways good info! Those sneaking little things can throw people off sometimes when questioning things.

Answer (score 3):

I would make the nextPreviousButton a flex container and do the following:

```
.nextPreviousButton {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center
}
```

Comment: Hey this worked! You forgot the s at the end of buttons and a semi-colon. FYI. *wink*

Comment: Read up on flexbox. I did and it has changed my world. So easy to use and it really comes in handy with how reactive your webpages end up becoming by nature. Definitely less to worry about when you do media queries

Comment: This is what many people in past forums have recommended to me. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

If you need the buttons stick to the bottom and also be centralised then first add these css to the div covering your content

```
.nextPreviousButtons{
width:100%;
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}

.cover {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

<div class="cover">
<div class="nextPreviousButtons">
  <a href="#" class="previous round">&#8249;</a>
  <a href="about.html" class="next round">&#8250;</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.nextPreviousButtons{
width:100%;
text-align:center;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

use this!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code , this will help you..

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.previous {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}

.next {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.round {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.nextPreviousButtons {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="nextPreviousButtons">
    <a href="#" class="previous round">&#8249;</a>
    <a href="about.html" class="next round">&#8250;</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code too :

```
div.nextPreviousButtons {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }
```